# Giving an $A/I-$module $M$ is same as giving an $A-$module $M$ such that for each element $a\in I$ the $A-$module homomorphism $\phi_a:M\to M$

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

> Let $A$ be a ring and $I$ be an ideal. Show that giving an $A/I$-module $M$ is same as giving an $A$-module $M$ such that for each element $a\in I$ the corresponding $A$ module homomorphism $\phi_a:M\to M$ (given by $\phi_a(m)=a\cdot m$) is zero.

I am unable to proceed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, to proceed, you would have to figure out a likely candidate for an $A$ module structure and examine it. The most obvious one is what you want.

Hint:

You are given a multiplication $\phi_{a+I}:M\to M$ for each $a+I\in R/I$.

What would happen if you let $\phi_a=\phi_{a+I}$ for each $a\in R$?

Answer (score 0):

Take the canonical surjection $\phi: A \to A/I$.

Consider by restriction of scalars, where an $A/I$ module $M$ is just an abelian group $M$ along with a ring morphism $\rho:A/I  \to \mathrm{End}  M$. In this case, $M$ can also be given a natural $A$-module structure by following morphisms: $\rho \circ \phi: A  \to \mathrm{End}(M)$. In this case, the morphism factors through $A/I$ so clearly $\rho \circ \phi(i)=0 \in \mathrm{End}(M)$ for any $i \in I$.

So, these things are "really the same."